# Single line for loop with two returns in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I would like to return two values from a single line for loop in brackets.

```
x,y = [xval, yval for xval, yval in zip(x,y) if condition]
```

This gives me a syntax error. I am only able to run the this like:

```
xy = [[xval,yval] for xval, yval in zip(x,y) if condition]
x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]
```

which is not very beautiful. Is there a way to run similar to the top example?

Im running all of this on Linux using python-3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `unzip` them:

```
x, y = zip(*[[xval,yval] for xval, yval in zip(x,y) if condition])
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is iterate over zipped tuples from 2 lists, you can create a for loop over the tuples with destructuring:

```py
for x,y in [(xval,yval) for xval, yval in zip(liste1,liste2) if condition]:
  print(x,y)
```

I you are trying to eliminate tuples from two lists based on a condition and get the filtered lists back, then Netwave's answer is correct.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Right, sorry I thought it was self explanatory. I'll add some comments.